# what camera capture output settings do I have to choose for live detection when image processing is quite time intense

Tags: swift, camera

I have quite time consuming OpenCV image processing action, which takes about 1 sec to process when I take a photo. In a live detection situation I do not get any output, since I guess the camera is feeding the process with new frames and it can not catch up with the image processing. Here is the code:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,
                   from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        let image: UIImage = CameraUtil.imageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer)

        self.contourView.image = OpenCVWrapper.convert(image) // this is the time intense OpenCV image processing
 }
```

I guess I can only feed the image processing every 1-2 sec in order to get this working. How would I do that? Or is there another solution? Maybe some clever camera settings?

Comment: wha's the purpose of using the OpenCV while recording ? & What're you trying to achieve

Comment: I am getting the contour of a shape and I want to see the result in a live detection before I take a photo.

Comment: I tried to reduce the frames per second setting with device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 1) by setting it to one frame per second, but this did not work. I guess the process is slightly over one second and therefore causing an overload

Comment: I have also checked how this would work in Python and it works fine. I can detect the contour in a live detection. This is also using OpenCV. So it has to do something with the Swift/Objective C setting